# User relationships. Override mysite.com/relationships page with views

Tags: views, users

Is there any chance to override mysite.com/relationships page with views? I guess the answer would be yes. But how? Can somebody explain to me in details. :)

P.S. I've tried to create my own page view, with path /relationships, but there's so much settings... messed up me :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution or the best practice. There is a low overhead, small module called [Empty Page](http://drupal.org/project/empty_page) that strips the content from a page. Use that and then put blocks in regions. It's great for creating elaborate front pages too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible (though somewhat fiddly) and we've done so on our site. I probably don't know Drupal well enough to pre-empt any howto questions, but I had [a question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/25294/3966) about it (now resolved) that I posted [a screenshot of the View configuration](http://www.flickr.com/photos/owenblacker/6978926279) to, so you might find those helpful.

If you have any specific questions on our implementation, drop them in the comments and I'll update this answer with more detail.

I should disclaim that our site uses UR in a Twitter paradigm, so relationships are unidirectional but may be reciprocated: Alice can follow Bob but that neither implies that Bob follows Alice nor prevents Bob from doing so.