# User Relationships view showing the right number of users, but showing my profile link, not theirs

Tags: 7, views, users

I'm not very good with Views and Panes, but I've *almost* completely managed to get what I want working.

I have [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) configured to have non-reciprocal relationships (so like Twitter, where "A follows B" does not necessarily imply that "B follows A"). I have a Pane that displays users followed by $current_user and I have cloned it to a new Pane displaying users following $current_user.

The Panel is almost working perfectly, with one exception — it is showing me the right number of profile links, but they're all links to $current_user's profile with $current_user's avatar, rather than links to $following_users' profiles with their avatars.

I changed the Fields section in the Pane definition to point to the requestee User profile picture and the requestee UID, but this doesn't seem to have fixed it. It's not the database query coming out wrong, I'm just displaying the wrong values for each relationship in *this* Pane.

I'm sure this is really very obvious, I just can't spot the setting I need to change from requeste*e* to requeste*r* in the Views Pane interface.

Anyone able to point me to where I'm missing the obvious bit of configuration?

---

**Edit:** I've taken [a screenshot of the configuration interface](http://www.flickr.com/photos/owenblacker/6978926279) (linked, rather than embedded, as you'll want to look at it in a bigger scale than embedding allows). The Custom text in the Fields reads `<a href="/user/[uid]">[field_user_image]</a>`. In the Contextual filters, I've set the Requester user filter to Exclude. The Argument input reads as follows:

[image]

**Edit 2:** Looking in the Custom text (`<a href="/user/[uid]">[field_user_image]</a>`), I have Replacement patterns available:

- `[field_user_image]` == User: My profile picture
- `[uid]` == User: Uid
- `[nothing]` == Global: Custom text
- `%1` == User relationships: Requester user title
- `!1` == User relationships: Requester user input
- `%2` == User relationships: Requestee user title
- `!2` == User relationships: Requestee user input

But I can't work out how to make use of `%1` or `!1` in order to get the requeste*r*'s `[uid]` or `[field_user_image]`, rather than that of the currently-logged-in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I was using the requeste*e* fields when I should have been using the requeste*r* fields. What was:

> [image: Incorrect fields]

Should have been:

> [image: Correct fields]

Problem solved.

Comment: Hi from UR maintainer ;). Views integration and especially documentation is quite lacking unfortunately. It would be great if you document what you did and how you did it somewhere on d.o or anywhere else (just give us the URL, e.g. by contacting me directly or opening an issue). Exported  views/features would also be interesting and/or suggestions/code on how to improve our default views.

Comment: @Berdir Ah, hi! The problem I had boiled down to my lack of familiarity on Views configuration and misreading Requester and Requestee. For non-reciprocal relationships, it's mildly confusing (as is that reciprocation amends the existing relationship, rather than creating a new unidirectional relationship). I'm not sure there's much more I can suggest, tbh, pticly as it's a private site that I'm NDA'd about, so I can't give you URLs. If you have any specific questions, I'd be happy to answer them on owen dot blacker at iris hyphen worldwide dot com, if that helps?

Comment: @Berdir Ich habe nür ein bisschen Deutsch, also kann'ich nicht auf Deutsch emailen. Ich kann auf Französisch lesen und schrieben, wenn möchten Sie nicht auf Englisch emailen.